# How fetch database using web service php

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl

I need to display database table content in php using web service. in there i used WSDL service with php. this is i tried code,

**Test.php**

```
<?php

/* Initialize webservice with your WSDL */
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:23995/Service1.svc?wsdl");


/* Invoke webservice method with your parameters, in this case: Function1 */
$response = $client->__soapCall("SelectUserDetails", array());



/* Print webservice response */
print_r($response);

?>
```

**Output**

```
> stdClass Object ( [SelectUserDetailsResult] => stdClass Object (
> [schema] => [any] => 1rooter12345rooter@gmail.com
> 2kal123ukkal@gmail.com 3sam123uksam@gmail.com 4net1234uknet@gmail.com
> ) )
```

How can i display these database values in HTML table with php

Comment: Your $response is an Object. So you can get the value of 'any' by $response->SelectUserDetailsResult->any

Comment: @Shan can you provide some sample code.. please,because i am new to web service.

Answer (score 0):

As per your output the response is an Object.If you are not familiar with PHP objects [read this](https://www.google.ae/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjRtIP2va3SAhUCEJoKHTGJCQIQFggiMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Flanguage.types.object.php&usg=AFQjCNEPSImqA8ypMEoD82q-E3E3_ZwA_g), As an example i can provide you the following code to access the Objects.
In PHP you can access and object by the following way :

```
$myObject = new stdClass(); //creating an object for demo
$myObject->name = 'My Name';
$myObject->address = 'My address1';

echo $myObject->name; // Output: My Name

echo $myObject->address; // Output: My address1
```

In the response, variable $response have the following members :

```
SelectUserDetailsResult // An Object with two members ('schema' & 'any'). In which schema is null, but you have some data in the member 'any'.
```

You can access the member 'any' as shown below :

```
$allEmails = $response->SelectUserDetailsResult->any;
```

By this way you can use this variable to print its value in any html.

Comment: shan what is the meaning of  ''any''

Comment: @SachithMW see output response in the question, there is a member variable 'any'

Comment: shan, ok according to this question and his output suppose 1 = userid rooter = username 12345 = password rooter@gmail.com = email ,then how to get all username in the database and how fetch these values in table

Comment: @Shan "1rooter12345rooter@gmail.com" is not a single email. which is
1 = userID
rooter = username
12345 = password
rooter@gmail.com = email
how can get each values separately ,i mean 1 for id column rooter for username column likewise

Comment: It is really hard to split the username, password & email from this string, since there is no seperator / no common pattern.

Comment: Shan, suppose c# appication return dataset like this.how to get each values, coz i also faced this probem. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42457533/how-to-print-database-content-using-wsdl-and-soap-web-services

Comment: If you can format the output of SelectUserDetails() that would be better.

Comment: @Shan Thanks shan :) can you provide some sample code to format the output of SelectUserDetails() ,